# IntersectionObserver Polyfill in an iFrame (Safari, IE11)

Tags: javascript, safari, internet-explorer-11, intersection-observer

I have an application that creates an iFrame, within that iFrame I need to observe if an element has become visible.

IntersectionObserver is not supported in IE or Safari, so I'm forced to use the polyfill: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill

Like most things, it's best described as an image:[image: Overview of the Issue]

Notice "Observed: 0" above, that's the `intersectionRatio`.  In browsers that have a native implementation, this reports the fraction of the element that's visible.  In the current state of the image it would report `1`.

Here's little snippet of what I'm doing with the observable and it's options:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('inner-root').contentDocument
var bod = doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

// Attaching the observable p tag:
var obs = document.createElement('p')
obs.id = 'observe-me'
obs.innerHTML = 'Observe this!'
innerBox.appendChild(obs)

// Setup the observer
// Can root any: documentElement, body, or innerBox (all work in Chrome)
var options = {
  root: doc.documentElement,
  //root: innerBox,
  // root: bod,
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}
var callback = function(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    result.innerHTML = 'Observed: ' + entry.intersectionRatio
  })
}
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options)
var reSelectedObs = doc.getElementById('observe-me')
reSelectedObs.style.background = 'orange'
observer.observe(reSelectedObs)
})()
```

Here's the full source: https://github.com/Kikketer/ieframe-observe/blob/w3c-polyfill/index.html

And you can demo it here: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kikketer/ieframe-observe/w3c-polyfill/index.html

I fear that I'll just have to write some sort of custom observer for the elements I have but I have a feeling what I write will somewhat look like the polyfill.

Has anyone had any luck with a situation like this?  Is there something I'm missing with the polyfill?

Comment: I could reproduce your problem, but, with reference to [this thread](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/236) and [this thread](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues/297), I suggest you post this issue to [IntersectionObserver issues](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/issues) and verify whether it works well with iframes and IE or safari browser.